# Why does osx 'find' utility require a path?

Tags: macos, terminal

On linux, the default `find` command ((GNU findutils) 4.4.2 on my system) has an *optional* path parameter, which defaults to current directory (the common case).  From man page:

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]
```

On OSX, `find` *does not* have an optional path parameter:

```
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

I find this quite annoying.  Has anyone solved this issue with a clever command alias/shell function, or perhaps by installing a different version of find?

Comment: This is completely OT for SO, but historically `find` always required a path - it became optional in Linux but that is by no means standard. Typically you just type `.` for the path when searching from the current directory, e.g. `find . -name foo.txt`.

Comment: @PaulR sorry, I wasn't sure if this would be OT or not.  I found some other questions asking about command line usage.  Maybe they were old, before other stack exchange domains went up.  Where would this belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X uses BSD find, which has historically required a path. You can install GNU findutils via MacPorts or the like.

Comment: Or create a simple shell script...

Comment: Why a shell script when a function will do?

Comment: brew install findutils installed gfind which I could alias.  Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because it doesn't necessitate installing MacPorts or something similar.

Comment: You don't need to install anything to have functions; they're part of bash.